# Avoid jquery.validation and use ajaxsumbit + HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I want to send emails from my contact form, I'm using HTML5 form and jquery.validation + jquery.form + jquery1.4.2.

The form works but I don't like that alert messages when you don't write in a required box, I prefer to use the HTML5 alerts on this case.

How I can avoid jquery.validate and just send the email and give to the client a "done" message.

This is the actual script:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#formulario').validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                    url: 'enviar.php',
                    success: function() {
                        $('#formulario').hide();
                        $('#formulario-contacto').append(
                            "<p>Tu mensaje ha sido enviado correctamente.</p><p><strong>Gracias por contactar conmigo.</strong></p><p>Me pondré en contacto contigo lo antes posible</p><p><a href='contacto.html'>Mostrar Formulario</a></p>"
                            )
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using jquery validation use the submit function.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#formulario').submit(function() {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            url: 'enviar.php',
            success: function() {
                $('#formulario').hide();
                $('#formulario-contacto').append("<p>Tu mensaje ha sido enviado correctamente.</p><p><strong>Gracias por contactar conmigo.</strong></p><p>Me pondré en contacto contigo lo antes posible</p><p><a href='contacto.html'>Mostrar Formulario</a></p>")
            }
        });
     });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but that send emails, but give me a white screen on "enviar.php", its now working properly